# Google Maps Api - How can I get coordinates for a "Searched Place/Zone"?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So, I have some experience with Google Maps API, and have read some questions similar to mine around here, ie. [Google Maps API - Getting Street Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835623/google-maps-api-getting-street-coordinates)

Now, what I need to get done is, To query Google Maps API with a **Zone** argument, and get its coordinates as response (preferably in JSON format), *queries should be performed within one city only*. 
Let's say that city is Medellin, Colombia **(coords: lat: 6.236165; long: -75.575262)**, And that **my query(zone) is**: *"Poblado"* (a district inside Medellin), **As a result of such query, I'd like to have its coordinates returned**.

How can I accomplish this task?

Please, help me,

As always thank you in advance,

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [component filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ComponentFiltering) of Google Geolocation API.

Comment: Looks very promising, And Spot On! Thank you. I'll give it a shot, and report shortly. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. this makes the distinction and makes the query I need. Thank you very much, and sorry for the delayed response.