# Finding nearest road using Google Places API:

Tags: ruby, google-places-api

In the Ruby application which I'm developing, given latitude and longitude of a point, I need to find the nearest road/highway to the point.

Can someone tell me how I can go about this using Google Places API?

I have tried giving a certain radius and finding the roads using the `'types:"route"'` parameter but it gives me "Zero results" as the output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API - Getting Street Coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835623/google-maps-api-getting-street-coordinates)

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Molle. But in my application, I have points which are not recognized by Google as origin/destination to use in the Directions API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google Places API is not designed to return nearby geographical locations, it is designed to return a list of nearby `establishments` and up to two `locality` or `political` type results to to help identify the area you are performing a Place Search request for.

The functionality you are requesting would be possible with the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) by passing the lat, lng to the `latlng` parameter of the HTTP reverse geocoding request:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=41.66547000000001,-87.64157&sensor=false

Comment: Thanks Chris ! That clarifies a lot

Answer (score 1):

Old question but we have an answer now. You can use [Nearest Roads API](https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/nearestRoads) by google. It does returns the closest road segment for each point.

I have implemented in one project and it does works. Although you must keep in mind that The points passed do not need to be part of a continuous path otherwise you will find next road(parallel road) which may not be important to you.

Comment: If you want snapping use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap