# Names of streets adjacent to a building in Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api, google-roads-api

I'm retrieving geocoordinates for particular locations (e.g. a trainstation) using the Google Maps Places API.

I would now like to get the names of streets adjacent to the building (e.g. on two or three sides of the building).

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Finding nearest road using Google Places API:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778011/finding-nearest-road-using-google-places-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use Roads API -- **[Nearest Roads](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/nearest)** which returns the closest road segment for each given point.

See sample request:
https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/nearestRoads?points=40.675138,-73.949893|40.674904,-73.949919&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Which returns the place IDs for roads St Marks Ave and Nostrand Ave in Brooklyn, NY:

```
{
    snappedPoints: [
        {
            location: {
                latitude: 40.675207313469635,
                longitude: -73.94988632960607
            },
            originalIndex: 0,
            placeId: "ChIJ-fmHuZxbwokR9DK_otCAI-8"
        },
        {
            location: {
                latitude: 40.67490969962758,
                longitude: -73.95002762271577
            },
            originalIndex: 1,
            placeId: "ChIJeTc98pxbwokR7npFqW-oC58"
        }
    ]
}
```

Place IDs can be used with other Google APIs, including the [Places API](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/places/) and the [Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places). For example, if you need to get road names for the snapped points returned by the Roads API, you can pass the `placeId` to the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) or the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start).

Hope this helps!