# Google maps how to force marker on the nearest road

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am doing a vehicle traking project, i am getting coordiantes from the databases, and showing on the google maps. 
**here is my code.....!!**

```
function get_coordinates(checkbox){
    var v_id=checkbox.id;
    if(checkbox.checked){
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        hr.open("POST", "fetch_coordinates.php", true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
                var lat=data.loc.lat;
                var lon=data.loc.lon;
                addmarker(lat,lon,v_id);
            }
        }
         hr.send("id="+v_id);   
    } else{
        var mark = markers[v_id]; // find the marker by given id
        mark.setMap(null);
        delete markers[v_id];

    }    
}
function addmarker(lat,lon,v_id){
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        id: v_id,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        zoom: 8,
        map: map,
        title: 'Vehicle No: '+v_id,
        icon: 'live.gif',
        optimized:false

    });
    markers[v_id] = marker;
    bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon));
   // map.setOptions({center:new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon),zoom:8});
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

But the problem is, sometimes i get GPS coordiantes which are 1,2 inches away from the road (possibly because of less precison of device or signal distortion etc)
How should I force my marker to automatically adjust on the road? Is there a some way, using direction rendering or any other hint ??? please help

Comment: Directions Service is probably what you are looking for. You can find nearest street with this service.Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835623/google-maps-api-getting-street-coordinates and https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

Answer (score 0):

In 2017 the right way to do it is the Roads API Snap to Roads service.

You can read about this web service on

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap

> The Google Maps Roads API takes up to 100 GPS points collected along a route, and returns a similar set of data, with the points snapped to the most likely roads the vehicle was traveling along. Optionally, you can request that the points be interpolated, resulting in a path that smoothly follows the geometry of the road.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro

You can use your desired url to get json request..

In the Coding section you can write this code to get the location on the road..

```
    Marker liveloc;
    JSONObject obj1=new JSONObject(s);
    JSONArray arr1=obj1.getJSONArray("routes");

    for (int i=0;i<arr1.length();i++){

    JSONObject obj2=arr1.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray arr2=obj2.getJSONArray("legs");

    JSONObject obj3=arr2.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject obj4=obj3.getJSONObject("start_location");
    String k=obj4.getString("lat");
    String k2=obj4.getString("lng");
    double k3=Double.parseDouble(k);
    double k4=Double.parseDouble(k2);
    LatLng myloc=new LatLng(k3,k4);

    if (liveloc !=null){
        liveloc.remove();
        }
   liveloc=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myloc));

}
```

You need to get the first start location from the json request..

Hope it helps...