# Google map marker show outside the road in swift 5

Tags: swift, google-maps

I am using google map in swift 5. I have used marker. Sometime marker shows outside the road. Here is the image
[image]
 I have used bellow code for google map

```
let marker = GMSMarker()
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lon)
marker.title = description
marker.icon = UIImage(named: "item_car_idle")
marker.rotation = CLLocationDegrees(heading)
marker.map =  self.googleMap
marker.infoWindowAnchor = self.getInfoWindowAnchorFor(Double(heading))
var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
self.googleMap.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding:50.0))
self.googleMap.selectedMarker = marker
```

how to fix my marker on road not outside. Please help me

Comment: Where is the location coming from? Through an iOS device or any external source ?

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com external device

Comment: @iOSArchitect.com it is come from car tracking device

Comment: Am not sure about the answer. This link might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22880381/google-maps-how-to-force-marker-on-the-nearest-road