# showing street view using google api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I am using `google api` v3 for showing street view its working for some place but some place where  its not showing street view example (715 MORAGA ROAD , MORAGA) there its working if we take (950 COUNTRY CLUB DRIVE , MORAGA CA 94556) its not working  here is my code :

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Street View service</title>
                <style>
                  html, body, #map-canvas {
                    height: 100%;
                    margin: 0px;
                    padding: 0px
                  }
                </style>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
            <script>
            var latitude=null;
            var longitude=null;
            var fenway;
            var map;
            var panoramaOptions;
            function initialize() {
             var value = '950 COUNTRY CLUB DRIVE , MORAGA CA 94556';
            alert("value"+value);
            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
            $.ajax({
              url:"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+value+"&sensor=false",
              type: "POST",
              success:function(res){
            latitude=res.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
               alert("latitude"+latitude);
            longitude=res.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
            alert("longitude"+longitude);
             var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
              var mapOptions = {
                center: fenway,
                zoom: 14
              };
              var map = new google.maps.Map(
                  document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
              var panoramaOptions = {
                position: fenway,
                pov: {
                  heading: 34,
                  pitch: 10
                }
              };
              var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
              console.log(panoramaOptions);
              map.setStreetView(panorama);
            }});
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div>
            <div id="pano" style="position:absolute; left:410px; top: 8px; width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Your question is worded in a way that is difficult to understand. What is your actual issue? What have you tried so far?

Comment: [Works for me at 215 Moraga Rd](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_Streetview_lookAtB.html?snaptoroad=715%20MORAGA%20ROAD%20,%20MORAGA) and [950 Country Club Dr](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_Streetview_lookAtB.html?snaptoroad=950%20COUNTRY%20CLUB%20DRIVE%20,%20MORAGA%20CA%2094556)

Comment: That is a typo in the text of my comment, the link is to [715 Moraga Rd](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_Streetview_lookAtB.html?snaptoroad=715%20MORAGA%20ROAD%20,%20MORAGA)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple: there is no streetView available for this location.

AFAIK it's not documented, but you may assume that there must be a panorama available in a distance of **50 meters** from the position set for the streetView.

The nearest panorama for `950 COUNTRY CLUB DRIVE , MORAGA CA 94556` `(37.833037, -122.13019099999997)`
is located at `(37.833647, -122.12991799999998)`,  which is **72 meters** offset.

Currently there is no way to find the nearest panorama within a distance >50, so you may perform a check if there is a panorama available in 50 meters(see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewService ) and create the StreetViewPanorama only when a panorama is available.

Another possibility(used in geocodezip's example, that's why you see a panorama there):
A streetViewPanorama usually is placed on a road(google has taken the images via a car). Use the directionsService to get the nearest road(see [Google Maps API - Getting Street Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835623/google-maps-api-getting-street-coordinates/11842585#11842585) ) and use the road-coordinate as position for the streetView