# Google Maps reverse Geocoding

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm writing a speedometer and location app in Android Studio. Now I know there are loads of very good speedo apps and Im not trying to mimic those. I'm happy to show my speed in a TextView and not a gauge.

I have successfully (with the help of coders on Stack Overflow) created an app that shows current speed in km/h and a compass bearing(very basic).

I have read I can use Reverse Geocoding to get address details but id like to show just the street I am on and it's speed limit and then of course format the speed in the TextView accordingly (overspeed -Red etc) and have that data change as I move from street to street, speed zone to speed zone.

Has anyone seen where I can get examples or know of any resources I can get a hold of please?

Thanks in Advance

Nick

Answer (score 0):

I have never used geo location stuff on android applications but I guess you need to use the [Google Maps Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro). Here they talk about **Snap to roads**.

*"This service returns the best-fit road geometry for a given set of GPS coordinates. This service takes up to 100 GPS points collected along a route, and returns a similar set of data with the points snapped to the most likely roads the vehicle was traveling along. Optionally, you can request that the points be interpolated, resulting in a path that smoothly follows the geometry of the road."*.

I am not sure if this is what you really need but sounds like this would be good if I understood your problem correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to use is the [`speedLimits`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/speed-limits) of the Google Maps Road API. This parameter returns the speed limit of a road segment. It requires a `placeId` in the request and returns the speed limit of the place.

The request and response looks like this which could be found in the documentation:

Request:

```
https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/speedLimits?placeId=ChIJ1Wi6I2pNFmsRQL9GbW7qABM
    &placeId=ChIJ58xCoGlNFmsRUEZUbW7qABM
    &placeId=ChIJ9RhaiGlNFmsR0IxAbW7qABM
    &placeId=ChIJabjuhGlNFmsREIxAbW7qABM
    &placeId=ChIJcSAlFWpNFmsRMHlUbW7qABM
    &placeId=ChIJI2FUTGhNFmsRcHpAbW7qABM
    &placeId=ChIJiy6YT2hNFmsRkHZAbW7qABM
    &placeId=ChIJoR7CemhNFmsRQB9QbW7qABM
    &placeId=ChIJP2m_FWpNFmsRIHlUbW7qABM
    &placeId=ChIJtV7La2pNFmsRAGpHbW7qABM
    &placeId=ChIJW5JAZmpNFmsRegG0-Jc80sM
    &placeId=ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM
    &placeId=ChIJy8c0r2lNFmsRQEZUbW7qABM
    &key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Response:

```
{
  "speedLimits": [
{
  "placeId": "ChIJ1Wi6I2pNFmsRQL9GbW7qABM",
  "speedLimit": 60,
  "units": "KPH"
},
{
  "placeId": "ChIJ58xCoGlNFmsRUEZUbW7qABM",
  "speedLimit": 60,
  "units": "KPH"
},
{
  "placeId": "ChIJ9RhaiGlNFmsR0IxAbW7qABM",
  "speedLimit": 60,
  "units": "KPH"
},
{
  "placeId": "ChIJabjuhGlNFmsREIxAbW7qABM",
  "speedLimit": 60,
  "units": "KPH"
},
{
  "placeId": "ChIJcSAlFWpNFmsRMHlUbW7qABM",
  "speedLimit": 60,
  "units": "KPH"
},
{
  "placeId": "ChIJI2FUTGhNFmsRcHpAbW7qABM",
  "speedLimit": 60,
  "units": "KPH"
},
{
  "placeId": "ChIJiy6YT2hNFmsRkHZAbW7qABM",
  "speedLimit": 60,
  "units": "KPH"
},
{
  "placeId": "ChIJoR7CemhNFmsRQB9QbW7qABM",
  "speedLimit": 60,
  "units": "KPH"
},
{
  "placeId": "ChIJP2m_FWpNFmsRIHlUbW7qABM",
  "speedLimit": 60,
  "units": "KPH"
},
{
  "placeId": "ChIJtV7La2pNFmsRAGpHbW7qABM",
  "speedLimit": 60,
  "units": "KPH"
},
{
  "placeId": "ChIJW5JAZmpNFmsRegG0-Jc80sM",
  "speedLimit": 60,
  "units": "KPH"
},
{
  "placeId": "ChIJW9R7smlNFmsRMH1AbW7qABM",
  "speedLimit": 60,
  "units": "KPH"
},
{
  "placeId": "ChIJy8c0r2lNFmsRQEZUbW7qABM",
  "speedLimit": 60,
  "units": "KPH"
}
  ]
}
```

Then for getting the streets you may want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835623/google-maps-api-getting-street-coordinates/19593942#19593942).