# is it possible to get distance between current location and a street, avenue or area?

Tags: android, google-api, location, distance

all solutions about calculating distance are between two points.
my question is:
Is there any way to calculate the distance to a certain street?

suppose I want to calculate a distance from my location to a specific area or avenue, which have many streets to get there, in this case how to know the nearest street to me to get there?

here I have only one point (my location) while the destination point is variant and depends on my current location. what I know about destination is in a certain street or area, so how to calculate it?

another case for this issue, suppose I am away 10 meters from a certain street which is 1 km long.
I should be able to calculate that my distance is 10 meters from the beginning of that street, after this distance when enter the street, and for each meter I waked for 1 km it should be 0 meter distance from my location to this street, and when I exit it from the other side the distance should be calculating again from the end point of that street not from the beginning point, so when I get away from it about 5 meters it should calculate it as 5 meters not as 1005 meters.

---

Here is the requirement by example on google maps:

first let's see [Wall Street in NY city](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/40.7052323,-74.0074383/40.707155,-74.0107727/@40.7061093,-74.0094159,17.53z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e2) on map.

[image]

So the target destination is Wall Street.
Now if your current location in the cross of John Street with Water Street, my task is to lead you to the nearest point in Wall Street and the path will be as [this one](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/40.7068884,-74.0050023/40.7052537,-74.0075128/@40.706165,-74.0084484,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!4m1!3e2) (walk mode).

[image]

however if you are in the cross of Broad Street with Beaver Street then the destination to nearest point in Wall Street will be [like this one](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/40.704963,-74.0115765/40.7070807,-74.0106125/@40.7052671,-74.0119824,18.75z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e2) (walk mode):

[image]

this is my issue

---

is it possible? Do new APIs offer a solution for this?

any solutions or ideas?

Comment: A "distance" needs two points by definition. Some of the [geocoding services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding) will help you get (at least rough) coordinates for a street, avenue or area. A "nearest street to get you there" is more complicated because in practise you are asking for navigation instructions. For calculating the exact distance to a street you'll need to know its coordinate points and can get them e.g. from Mapzen as vector map data. The actual calculation then is a geometry problem: perpendicular distance to a line if possible, otherwise distance to the nearest point.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen thank you for replying, Exactly as you say, how to get the nearest point belong to a specific street from my location using google maps? I have two information, 1.my location coordinates . 2. the destination street name. now I want to get there as a shortest path to nearest point in that street, if I determine the nearest point then I will be able to go there by using the nearest street leads to it and get other navigation instructions. but how to get the nearest point belong to a street as a target destination point? this is the problem here.

Comment: down voting ... not a problem but give me a reason. I am looking for a solution for this issue, if anyone wants to down vote and knows a solution, go ahead but give me a solution please.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what it is that you really want in the end. Let's say you are in the city of Nantes in France and want to see the Eiffel tower in Paris: Do you want to know how far away is the Eiffel tower from your current location in Nantes or do you want to get driving/traveling instructions to the Eiffel tower either by a rental car or the TGV train? And downvotes are probably because this seems like quite a broad and not-so-specific question with not much background work visible from your side.

Comment: yes, you can but you need both latitude and longitude

Comment: @Saveen I have latitude and longitude coordinates for current location, and I looking for or need a method or way to get latitude/longitude of nearest location in targeted street, this is the issue here. any ideas?

Comment: @Eng.SamerT I have added my answer this way to get latitude and longitude of other street,city or any place than you find distance between any 2 points.. more information check from here https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/

Comment: @Eng.SamerT did you get my point ?

Answer (score 0):

hey yes you get latitude and longitude of searched location here i'll example how you can get.

You can use google **autocomplete** for searching any place.Then get **placeid** from autocomplete api then pass it to **details** api.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json

See pass the parameters

```
//Google Autocomplete
@GET(ApiConstants.GET_AUTOCOMPLETE)
Observable<GoogleAutocompleteSearchResponse> getAutoCompleteSearch(@Query("input") String input, @Query("key") String key, @Query("components") String components);

// Google Autocomplete places
@GET(ApiConstants.GET_AUTOCOMPLETE_PLACE)
Observable<GoogleAutoCompletePlacesResponse> getAutoCompletePlaces(@Query("placeid") String input, @Query("key") String key);
```

You can get latitude longitude in second one api.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First get the longitude, latitude of destination location

```
public Location getCoordinatesFromAddress(Context context,String strAddress) {

    Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(context);
    List<Address> address;
    Location destinationLoc = null;

    try {
        address = coder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 5);
        if (address == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Address location = address.get(0);
        destinationLoc = new Location("Destination");

        destinationLoc.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
        destinationLoc.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return destinationLoc;
   }
```

As you mentioned you have latitude and longitude of your present location. Use that to create your current location.

```
Location locationA = new Location("Present location ");

locationA.setLatitude(latA);
locationA.setLongitude(lngA);
```

Next after getting latitudes and longitudes of your destination and source(present) locations you can easily calculate the distance between them 
e.g

```
float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

It will give you the distance b/w two geo locations in meters.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835623/google-maps-api-getting-street-coordinates). Also take a look over [this API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) from google.

I guess what you want looks like this:
   - get targeted street coordinates [lat, long]
   - get nearby places from google,
   - search the nearest place.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you can get address of both destination and origin, then by following method you can get distance between address.

For which you need to pass either address (origin/destination) or latitude / longitude (origin/destination)

1) Here the origin parameter can be like following , if address is provided

```
origins=Bobcaygeon+ON|24+Sussex+Drive+Ottawa+ON
```

2) Where as , if latitude / longitude is provided , then following will be the format.

```
origins=41.43206,-81.38992
```

3) If you are able to get place ID , then this will be the format

```
origins=place_id:ChIJ3S-JXmauEmsRUcIaWtf4MzE
```

The following example uses latitude/longitude coordinates to specify the destination coordinates

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998&destinations=40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.6905615%2C-73.9976592%7C40.659569%2C-73.933783%7C40.729029%2C-73.851524%7C40.6860072%2C-73.6334271%7C40.598566%2C-73.7527626%7C40.659569%2C-73.933783%7C40.729029%2C-73.851524%7C40.6860072%2C-73.6334271%7C40.598566%2C-73.7527626&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Same request for encoded polyline will be

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998&destinations=enc:_kjwFjtsbMt%60EgnKcqLcaOzkGari%40naPxhVg%7CJjjb%40cqLcaOzkGari%40naPxhV:&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

As explained by other's the general method to find shortest distance using  API is

```
float distance = firstLocation.distanceTo(secondLocation);
```

For more information go through [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [*Haversine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula to calculate distance between two points if you know the latitude and longitude for each of them.

- Node Package: [Haversine Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/haversine)
- Gradle: [Gradle Haversine](https://www.versioneye.com/clojure/haversine:haversine/0.1.0)